# Ruby on Rails : RVM and Rubygems Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I had just done "rvm rubygems 1.3.5" and "gem install rails -v 2.2.2", and both worked correctly and I was able to use rails for awhile.

Now it seems like rails and rubygems just suddenly disappeared, so I reinstalled rubygem, but now trying to reinstall rails, I'm getting

```
ERROR:  While executing gem (NameError) uninitialized constant gem::Installer::ENV_PATHS
```

I get the same error when trying to do

```
gem update --system
```

Would appreciate any help.

And my

```
gem list shows rails(2.2.2)
```

I'm trying to find other people with similar issues, and looks like it might have something to do with GEM PATH but I'm not sure where to go from there. In "gem environment" I get this for GEM PATHS:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371 <br />
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global <br />
```

Comment: Which ruby version you have used? I think it may be because of you used old ruby version.

Comment: USe "rvm list"   
"ruby -v"  
"rvm use 1.9.2"

Comment: 1.8.7, but it was used correctly early on.

I'm trying to find other people with similar issues, and looks like it might have something to do with GEM PATH but I'm not sure where to go from there. In "gem environment" I get this for GEM PATHS:
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371 
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global

Comment: I have to use 1.8.7, nothing more current, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced same issue with 1.3.5 please upgrade your rubygems version to 1.3.7 or 1.4.2

if you are using RVM

> rvm install rubygems 1.4.2

or else try

> sudo gem update --system 1.4.2

Answer (score 7):

Type below command in your console.This worked for me.

```
   rvm @global do gem uninstall -ax rubygems-bundler
```